# Remove template name from URL AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularJS $routeProvider,

//Template

//Routing

```
function ($routeProvider) {
       $routeProvider.
          when('/_profileView', {
              templateUrl: '_profileView.htm',
              controller: '_profileViewController'
          }).
          when('/', {
              templateUrl: '_homeView.htm',
              controller: '_homeViewController'
          }).
          when('/_homeView', {
              templateUrl: '_homeView.htm',
              controller: '_homeViewController'
          })}
```

Is there a way to remove the template name from the Url like this:
   Example.com/#/_homeView    ---->  Example.com/

Comment: one is the way of removing hash tag but if you want to remove url name use ng-include directive in your html and set just root in routing then when anyone click the menu include html when another hide previos

Answer (score 0):

If you would use `ui.router` instead of `ng-route` it would solve your problem.
For example:

```
angular.module('app',[ 'ui.router' ])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
    $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url : "/",
        templateUrl : "_homeView.htm",
        controller: "_homeViewController"
    }).state('profile', {
        url : "/_profileView",
        templateUrl: "_profileView.htm",
        controller: "_profileViewController"
    })
 });
```

Inside the `url` attribute if you give just `"/"` the outcome is just what you need.

Another **note** on using `ui.router` instead `ng-route` -- I experienced that, if you want to use nested `ng-view`-s it's possible only with `ui.router`.

I hope this helps, cheers!